# How to find a substring within a string without taking whitespaces into account and knowing the original indices of string

Tags: python, string

Normally I use `str.find()` to find a substring in python.

I have a special case at the moment

1. First I want to ignore the whitespaces
   For example

   ```
   s1= ' first words s t r i n g last words '
   s2= 'string'
   s3= 's tring'
   s4= any other combination with the spaces
   ```

   I want find to return true when I search `s2` and `s3` in `s1`
2. Secondly I want to get the starting and ending index of the substring within the original string

   It could be that there are many spaces in the original string, for example

   ```
    s1= ' first words s t r    i n g last words '
   ```

   I would like to have indices starting at `s` and ending at `g` in the original string.

**EDIT1**

*To clarify the spaces are insignificant in both source and the target string.*

Thanks

Comment: Would you expect a search for `"s t"` to succeed with a target string of `"st"`? In other words, are spaces significant in the search string but not otherwise in the target?

Comment: You can use a regex search as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158989/python-regex-search-in-string) one

Comment: They are insignificant on both source and target strings, +1 for asking. I will edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern by first removing the spaces in the string you're looking for, then putting `' *'` (any number of spaces) between each character. As you want to be able to use any special character in the search string, we also escape them :

```
import re

def find_with_spaces(pattern, text):
    pattern = pattern.replace(' ', '')
    pattern_re = re.compile(' *'.join(map(re.escape, pattern)))

    m = pattern_re.search(text)
    if m:
        return m.start(), m.end()


s1= ' first words s { r * n g? last words '
s2= 's{r*ng?'

start, end = find_with_spaces(s2, s1)
print(start, end)
print(s1[start:end])

# 13 25
# s { r * n g?
```

The regex pattern created and used by the function in this case was `r's *\{ *r *\* *n *g *\?'`. Note that the end index is 25, while the last '?' is at index 24 - that lets you use `s1[start:end]` to get the matched substring.

```
s3= ' * ng?la'
start, end = find_with_spaces(s3, s1)
print(start, end)
print(s1[start:end])

# 19 28
# * n g? la
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like a nice solution, but it is not working if the 'pattern' contains '*' in it. The following is the error. 'sre_constants.error: multiple repeat at position 12'

Comment: Hi, I have found out that it has problem with every special character that regex uses, for example now it is giving problem with '?'. there is 're.escape()' for it, I tried applying it naively but it didnt work. I tried re.escape(pattern). Thanks

Comment: Right, I should have taken care of them all with `'*'`. Done!

Comment: You have to escape every single character independently just before joining them, otherwise you would also insert `' *'` between the backslashes and the special characters, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore the spaces from any string, you could use `string.replace(" ", "")`

To find the substring within a string you could use `string.find(substr)`

To find the location in  the original string from the result of `find` you will have to shift it by the number of spaces you removed prior to that point.

```
s1= ' first words s t r i n g last words '
s2= 'string'

s1_nospace=s1.replace(" ", "")
s2_nospace=s2.replace(" ", "")

nospace_index=s1_nospace.find(s2_nospace)

isnt_space = [not (x==" ") for x in s1]
# Cumulative sum of isnt_space
chars_before = reduce(lambda c, x: c + [c[-1] + x], isnt_space, [0])[1:]

start_index = chars_before.index(nospace_index+1)
end_index = chars_before.index(nospace_index+len(s2_nospace))

# start_index == 13
# end_index == 23
```

You could certainly clean it up and/or speed it up a bit but this should accomplish the task in a relatively readable way.

Comment: By doing that, you lose all the information about starting and ending indices of the substring.

Comment: Just count the non-space characters in the initial string and shift the result from find by the appropriate amount to account for the spaces.  I'll edit with an example.

Answer (score 0):

you may test this out

```
import re

# Part-1. Check for substring existence
s1= str(input("String>\t\t"))
s2 = str(input("Substring>\t"))
print("Is substring present in string?\t-",s2.replace(" ", "") in s1.replace(" ", ""))

# Part-2. Search for exact pattern and indices in original string
s2 = s2.replace(" ", "")
s2 = re.compile(" *".join(s2))  #Define the pattern  of the substring here
if(s2.search(s1)):              #Search for defined pattern in original string 
    print((s2.search(s1)).start(), (s2.search(s1)).end())
```

" *" is the pattern to be searched is after any character, any number of spaces, with * being the suitable quantifier. Sorry, I'm trying to getting used to giving runtime inputs and trying to minimize variable usage clumsily, but this works perfectly fine.